# AdMob/Unity - Rewarded Video are not showing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm using this code to create and load a Rewarded Video, when i click on the button, with, teorically it has to show, it doesn't. But, in my Debug shows that are instanced, loaded and, how i said, when i click on the button, the Debug says that is showing too. However, I've tested in my smartphone and an emulator and nothing appears.

```
public class AdRewardedVideo : MonoBehaviour {
    string VideoAdID = "THE ID HERE";
    RewardBasedVideoAd MyRewardedVideoAd;

    void Start() {
        MyRewardedVideoAd = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;
    }

    public void LoadVideoAd() {
        if (!MyRewardedVideoAd.IsLoaded()) {
            AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
            MyRewardedVideoAd.LoadAd(request,VideoAdID);
        }
    }

    public void showVideoAd() {
        if (MyRewardedVideoAd.IsLoaded()) {
            MyRewardedVideoAd.Show();
        } else {
            LoadVideoAd();
        }
    }
}
```